# ArgoCD: transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup argocd-repo-server

Tags: argocd

I am configuring ArgoCD, and all the pods are Running state like below.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n argocd -o wide
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP               NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
argocd-application-controller     1/1     Running   0          138m   172.16.195.218   worker-1    <none>           <none>
argocd-applicationset-controller  1/1     Running   0          138m   172.16.195.216   worker-1    <none>           <none>
argocd-dex-server                 1/1     Running   0          138m   172.16.59.213    worker-2    <none>           <none>
argocd-notifications-controlle    1/1     Running   0          138m   172.16.195.217   worker-1    <none>           <none>
argocd-redis                      1/1     Running   0          138m   172.16.59.214    worker-2    <none>           <none>
argocd-repo-server                1/1     Running   0          46m    172.16.59.216    worker-2    <none>           <none>
argocd-server                     1/1     Running   0          138m   172.16.59.215    worker-2    <none>           <none>
```

But when I create a new app, ArgoCD shows the following error.

> Unable to create application: application spec for test is invalid:
> InvalidSpecError: repository not accessible: rpc error: code =
> Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while
> dialing dial tcp: lookup argocd-repo-server on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp
> 172.16.59.215:50498->10.96.0.10:53: i/o timeout"

This error occurs when not only using private git repository but also public github repository. And `curl` to git repository from `worker-2` node is OK.

Maybe it seems that the connection from `argocd-server` to `argocd-repo-server` is timed out. But I cannot understand why this problem occurs.

**My Environment:**

- Rocky Linux 8.5
- kubeadm (1 Master Node + 2 Worker Nodes)
- Calico as CNI

Comment: can you actually view the repositories in the UI and validate that connections are good. are you managing declaratively or via argocd cli?

Comment: I have the same issue!

Comment: i have the same issue

Comment: Same issue! Not sure how to fix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your logs you've probably faced IP connectivity issue with DNS server. Apparently, due to inability to resolve domain names `argocd-server` cannot initiate connection to `argocd-repo-server`.

A general plan to you how to troubleshoot such issues:

1. be sure that your DNS pod is up & running in your K8s cluster.
2. be sure your pod has IP connectivity with K8s DNS server.
3. be sure your pod has access to UDP/53 of K8s DNS server.
4. be sure DNS entry that your pod's asking for is resolved, so `argocd-repo-server` is resolved to an IP address.

See that pretty explained guide for more details - [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and after hours debugging, I found it is because I installed core-dns after I install argocd.

So I just reset the whole cluster, and installed core-dns firstly then argocd, the issue was gone.

Comment: Same problem - restart of core-dns pods helped!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, I switched to the namespace of argocd and issued `kubectl rollout restart deployment` to restart all pods and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have calico based config but had the same issue when I started messing up with the argo server service.

With a clean setup, I used NodePort configuration for server instead of LoadBalancer.  Without further tunnelling the portal together with argo cli, both worked with the registry connection. Would recommend to try the same.

Answer (score 0):

For those arriving here because they had an issue configuring ArgoCD provider on Terraform, you need to set the `server_addr` like this :

- wrong : `https:my-argo-cd-server` | `https:my-argo-cd-server:443`
- good : `my-argo-cd-server:443`

Of course set the right port if yours is set on another one than the default https one.